# How to construct parametric bootstrap confidence intervals in R without using boot package?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, nonparametric

How can I construct parametric bootstrap confidence intervals in R without using the `boot` package?

Comment: As it stands that sounds like a pretty broad question. Why without the boot package? Is this for some class?

Comment: As an inspiration, I've posted pseudocode for a _non-_parametric bootstrap [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73238/alternatives-to-pvals-fnc-to-compute-confidence-intervals-for-fixed-effects/73288#73288). Shouldn't be too hard to adapt to the parametric case.